# CodeIgniter: Use get_post with XSS filtering on entire $_POST array

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss

Is there an easier way than

```
foreach($_POST as $x=>$y){
  $arr[$x] = $this->input->get_post($y, TRUE);
}
```

to just have the entire $_POST array cleaned with CI's XSS filter. Looking at the input library it seems though get_post() only accepts an individual variable rather than being able to clean the entire array and then return the array back.

Comment: Blanket filtering over application input is totally bogus. It will mangle potentially-valid input and will not reliably protect from XSS. The *only* way to be safe from XSS is to correctly escape every text string you interpolate into HTML, eg. using `htmlspecialchars`. CI's xss_clean does a quite amazingly blunt and silly set of string mangling even by the very very low standards of “XSS Protection” tools; you should not use it under any circumstances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you want it globally, but if you do... from ze manual:

If you want the filter to run automatically every time it encounters POST or COOKIE data you can enable it by opening your application/config/config.php file and setting this:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Arrgh! I can't believe I forgot about that. Constantly switching between Symfony and CI is frying my brain. Thanks!

Comment: This is now deprecated, XSS-filtering should be performed on output, not input.

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer for this is correct in a sense but the information is provided is not a suitable answer to the real problem which is XSS filtering in CI.

To further the comment by bobince some good reading at:

http://ponderwell.net/2010/08/codeigniter-xss-protection-is-good-but-not-enough-by-itself/

Either htmlspecialchars / htmlentities / urlencode on all output or go home. CI's XSS filter uses a dated and broken blacklist technique that fails a lot of XSS attacks.

Encode and validate. Always.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
```

returns all POST items with XSS filter

```
$this->input->post();
```

returns all POST items without XSS filter